# SQL Server Audit Event Log

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, audit

I'm struggling to get audit working using application logs on SQL Server 2012 based upon the various responses I've found here and Microsoft's documentation.  As a test, I executed the following script in Management Studio and it reported success.  However, when I deliberately fail a login, I don't see any records appearing in my OS log.

```
USE master
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess TO APPLICATION_LOG
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION HIPPA_Audit_Specification
FOR SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess 
    ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP)
    WITH (STATE = ON)
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

**Clarifying**: It works if I put the output to a file instead of the OS log.  If I create the object like this:

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT AuditDataAccess TO FILE ( FILEPATH ='C:\SqlAudit\' )
GO
```

...it works and I can retrieve the data using:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file ('c:\SqlAudit\AuditDataAccess_*.sqlaudit',default,default);
GO
```

What am I doing wrong with regard to using an OS Application Log?

**Edit**: If nothing, then am I just looking in the wrong place?  I brought up Windows 7 EventViewer and looked in each subtree of Event Viewer (local)/Windows Logs.  I also looked in Event Viewer (local)/Applications and Service Logs, but don't see an entry for SQL Server beyond the empty "Microsoft-SQLServerDataTools".

Comment: That should work. As a simplification, what happens if you specify the full path to the sqlaudit file (instead of a wildcard like you have now)?

Comment: The wildcard works.  I probably wasn't clear...files work.  OS application event logs don't.

Comment: Ah, my fault, I read it backwards. Hmm, I just did a test on my local instance. I got an event in the application log with eventid = 33205. You're not getting anything? Not even one for the audit starting?

Comment: Check if the user of sql server service has permissions to write to EventLog

Comment: @Ben:  no, I'm not getting anything.  I guess I'll try this on a different machine and see if it's something machine-specific.

Comment: @Max: my understanding is that any user can write to the application log, only the security log requires elevated permissions.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Tad Yes, event viewer require permissions also if you write a new event source, is this your case ? Where you write EventLog = Application and EventSource = ??

Comment: I'll toss this out something that everyone likely uses and could serve as an adjunct to auditing failed logins and that is creating a SQL Agent alert to email on login failure.  Useful if someone wants to know immediately about a failed login...

Answer (score 0):

It should be under Event Viewer / Windows Logs / Application, with event ID 33205.

[Understanding Audit Logging in SQL Server 2008](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/blog/default.aspx?p=e2550c9b-16f8-446d-ada1-a171f1e6a72a)

"Any authenticated user can read and write to the Windows Application event log. The Application event log requires lower permissions than the Windows Security event log and is less secure than the Windows Security event log." - [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx)